# Cant assign new enum value to variable

Tags: syntax, c#-4.0

I have an enum defined like so:

```
 public enum Direction
{
    Left,
    Right,
    Up,
    Down
}
```

And I the following variable in a class:

```
private Direction direction;
```

In the constructor, I assign the variable:

```
direction = Direction.Right;
```

Then, in a method in the same class, I try to assign a new Enum value:

```
direction = Direction.Down;
```

But it won't let me! It keeps going back to the Right value even thought the only place where it gets set is in the constructor!

What's going on? o_O

EDIT - MORE CODE

```
    namespace MyFirstGame
{
    public enum Direction
    {
        Left,
        Right,
        Up,
        Down
    }
}

using Microsoft.Xna.Framework;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Graphics;

namespace MyFirstGame
{
    public class Invader : Sprite, IMovable
    {
        private InvaderType invaderType { get; set; }
        private Direction direction;
        private Vector2 speed;

        public Invader(Texture2D image, Vector2 position)
            : base(image, position, new Point(30, 16), new Point(0, 0), new Point(2, 0))
        {
            direction = Direction.Right;
            speed.X += 30;
        }

        public override void Update(GameTime gameTime, Rectangle clientBounds)
        {
            timeSinceLastFrame += gameTime.ElapsedGameTime.Milliseconds;

            if (timeSinceLastFrame > milliSecondsPerFrame)
            {
                timeSinceLastFrame -= milliSecondsPerFrame;

                ++currentFrame.X;

                if (currentFrame.X >= SheetSize.X)
                {
                    currentFrame.X = 0;
                }

                Move(direction, clientBounds);
            }
        }

        public void Move(Direction direction, Rectangle clientBounds)
        {
            if (direction == Direction.Right)
            {
                //is invader 3 px from the right edge?
                //if yes: then drop
                //else keep on truckin' to the right!
                if (position.X >= (clientBounds.Width - (Image.Width + 3)))
                {
                    //position.X = 0;
                    position.Y += speed.X;

                    direction = Direction.Down;
                }
                else
                {
                    position.X += speed.X; //Speed
                }
            }
            else if (direction == Direction.Down)
            {
                speed.X *= -1;
                position.X += speed.X;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The method

Comment: Have you done a `Clean Solution` and then a `Build Solution`?

Comment: Your should post more code to help us understand your question.

Comment: Did as you suggested, but still the same.

Comment: If you put a break point in the constructor where the direction is set does it get hit more than once?

Comment: @InfernalBadger - No, just once.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, I am answering my own question :-)

As for why it didn't work. I know for one part why and for the other I don't.

The part I know:

I had this method call in my Update() method:

**Move(direction, clientBounds);**

But the thing is that Enums are structs. The parameter in the **Move(direction, clientBounds)** method is actually being copied! Any changes that take place inside the method have no affect on the original value of the variable. So anytime I ended up with the original value when passing out of the Move() method.

The thing I can't rely place right now is the fact that I removed the direction as a parameter from the Move method call and I now assign a new direction directly to the class level variable **private Direction direction;**. This seems to work perfectly :-) But why?

Comment: If that was your problem, why not simply pass by reference instead of passing by value? `Move(ref direction, clientBounds);` and similarly update the method signature. If `Move()` *must* change the value of `direction` at all - that definitely seems like a non-obvious side effect to me.

Comment: Yes, the ref modifier :-) For now I removed the direction parameter, since the `Move()` method is in the same class as the direction parameter. Instead of supplying direction from the outside, I now have the class itself decide when to change direction.

What exactly do you mean with _If `Move()` must change the value of direction at all - that definitely seems like a non-obvious side effect to me_? Why?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you don't have stale binaries (as pointed out by Oded)...

Set a breakpoint on the assignment, and make sure that it actually executes. Then, immediately after the assignment (use `Step Over`), verify the value of `direction`.

If it's correct at that point, then *something* else is causing it to be reset.

Comment: The value after the assignment is Down. But ones it goes out of it and back to the method again (it's a XNA game loop), it is back to Right again.

Comment: My guess it's a different instance of Invader.

Comment: But if that would be the case, then wouldn't the constructor run again? The invader is "loaded" into the game in the LoadContent method of XNA's Game1, which should just run once - when the game starts up.